# CSS HTML: Is there workaround for parent scaling and child position:fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So the problem occurs if we have parent element which is scaled and children elements with `position:fixed`:

```
.parent {
    transform: scale(2);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
}
.child {
    position:fixed;
}
```

It breaks the child `position:fixed` caused by `scale(2)` on the parent element. The problem has been known since 2 years ago. Is there a workaround for this problem?

I really have to use scale on the parent and position:fixed on the children for some reason.

Comment: I would like to see a link regarding this 'problem'. Since fixed removes it from the normal flow. What are you even trying to achieve is the main issue.

Comment: Since fixed positioned elements are independent from its parent elements, I think it is better to place it as a direct child of <body>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you want to position the child element. But I know that in your case the bottom and right attributes to position the child attribute don't work as expected. The top and left propterties do though.

To position the child element in the lower right corner I found the following workaround:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    .parent {
      transform: scale(2);
      transform-origin: 0 0 0;
      background-color: blue;
    }
    .child {
      position: fixed;
      left: calc(50vw - 100px);
      top: calc(50vh - 100px);
      background-color: red;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      parent
      <div class="child">child</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For some reason the viewport of the child gets increased by the scale of the parent. Because of that you have to decrease the viewport by 50% in case of a scaling by the factor of 2.

If this does not help you please let me know where you want to position the child element.

Comment: I see what you did here. I think this might work, I have not try it. It will be great if you put the example here for the others. For me @Pons Purushothaman solution works. Which to move those elements into body or a container which contains them all. Thank you